# Given is a binary tree and a LCA , find the number of pair of nodes which have this LCA?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Consider an infinite binary tree defined as follows.

> For a node labelled v, let its left child be denoted 2*v and its right child 2*v+1. The root of the tree is labelled 1.
>
> For a given n ranges [a_1, b_1], [a_2, b_2], ... [a_n, b_n] for which (a_i <= b_i) for all i, each range [a_i,b_i] denotes a set of all integers not less than a_i and not greater than b_i. For example, [5,9] would represent the set {5,6,7,8,9}.
>
> For some integer T, let S represent the union [a_i, b_i] for all i up to n.
>   I need to find the number of unique pairs (irrespective of order) of elements x,y in S such that the lca(x,y) = T

(Wikipedia has a pretty good explanation of what the [LCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor) of two nodes is.)

---

For example, for input:

```
A = {2, 12, 11}
B = {3, 13, 12}
T = 1
```

The output should be 6. (The ranges are [2,3], [12,13], and [11,12], and their union is the set {2,3,11,12,13}. Of all 20 possible pairs, exactly 6 of them ((2,3), (2,13), (3,11), (3,12), (11,13), and (12,13)) have an LCA of 1.)

And for input:

```
A = {1,7}
B = {2,15}
T = 3
```

The output should be 6. (The given ranges are [1,2] and [7,15], and their union is the set {1,2,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}. Of the 110 possible pairs, exactly 6 of them ((7,12), (7,13), (12,14), (12, 15), (13,14) and (13,15)) have an LCA of 3.)

Comment: A binary tree is its root node `class Node { Node parent, first, second; }`. You are using some weird notation that seems to be referring to the array indices at which you are storing node elements, but trees are not normally stored in arrays that way.

Comment: Can you provide a link describing exactly what you mean by "LCA", or describing your notation for the "tree"?

Comment: Numbers are not tree nodes.

Comment: I will do what I can, be patient while I solve this intriguing problem.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you done so far to solve the problem? Please demonstrate that you've put some effort into finding a solution.

Comment: @MaxWallace  I know to code a LCA of 2 given nodes in a binary tree. But this question is reverse of LCA thats why i need help!

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework, and you haven't confirmed that it isn't. If it is, you're impeding your own learning by asking on SO, as answers usually present a complete solution without leaving out details for you to fill in. Ask your professor and/or TA for help-- they'll usually be able to guide you to a solution without giving away too much.

Comment: @MaxWallace Next time i will take care about that.

Comment: This is really sad to see this question being asked here. This was a question set by me for an online test. The test has finished just now so this was asked right during the test. I wanted to add this as a comment but didn't have enough reputation to do that and hence putting this as an answer.

Comment: Do you have any proof of that? Where was the problem posted? We can certainly have this question along with its answers deleted. However, I don't think the answer here is anywhere near the intended answer, so maybe it's not a problem after all. I deleted my answer containing a better algorithm which would probably be accepted

Comment: @NiklasB. The question was part of a private test on [interview street](https://www.interviewstreet.com).

Comment: I would prefer the question be taken down as we will never be able to use this question again if someone else answers the question.

Comment: may I ask what the intended complexity of a solution was? I guess there's some input restrictions missing from the question, so we can't really tell.  If there's only one query, *O(n \* log n + log B \* log n)* is easy where *B* is the maximum b_i. For multiple (say *q*) queries we can get *O(n \* log n + q \* log B \* log n)*. I will flag the question to have it deleted.

Comment: That said, I think you can't prevent your problems from leaking, so if you want to ensure fairness, you should not reuse questions (although I understand that problems of this caliber are non-trivial to invent and set). Good job on this one, it's fairly interesting.

Comment: Even though the test is over we keep the question in our library for some future use. We discard any question which are available on searching on the internet, so this question if not deleted will become useless for us going forward. Yes the intended complexity was O(n * log n + q * log B * log n) n was max of 10^5 and all other numbers could be any of 32-bit signed integers.

Comment: I flagged the questions. The mods will decide whether to keep it or delete it. People will often paraphrase questions when they know they are not allowed to publish them, so you can't find them via internet search.

Comment: I also removed my *O(n log n + q * log n * log W)* answer, but people with above 20k reputation can still see it.

Comment: My bad there was only one query the expected time complexity was O(n*log n + n*log B).

Comment: Well it's cooler with multiple queries ;)

Comment: Yes that is possible but I didn't want to make the question too complicated as this was done for a recruitment test and wanted to just test the coding ability of the candidates in a simple to formulate solution.

Comment: @PraveenVaka: The question will remain open. Since it has an accepted answer already, I doubt someone else will write another answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is fairly simple to compute the LCA of two nodes in your notation, using this recursive method:

```java
int lca(int a, int b) {
    if(a == b) return a;
    if(a < b) return lca(b, a);
    return lca(a/2, b);
}
```

Now to find the union of the sets, we first need to be able to find what set a particular range represents. Lets introduce a factory method for this:

```java
Set<Integer> rangeSet(int a, int b){
    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>(b-a);
    for(int n = a; n <= b; n++) result.add(n);
    return result;
}
```

This will return a `Set<Integer>` containing all the integers contained in the range.

To find the union of these sets, just `addAll` their elements to one set:

```java
Set<Integer> unionSet(Set<Integer> ... sets){
    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(Set<Integer> s: sets)
        result.addAll(s);
    return result;
}
```

Now, we need to iterate over all possible pairs in the set:

```java
pairLcaCount(int t, Set<Integer> nodes){
    int result = 0;
    for(int x: nodes)
        for(int y: nodes)
            if(x > y && lca(x,y) == t) result++;
    return result;
}
```

Everything else is just glue logic, methods to convert from your input requirements to the ones taken here. For instance, something like:

```java
Set<Integer> unionSetFromBoundsLists(int[] a, int[] b){
    Set<Integer> [] ranges = new Set<Integer>[a.length];
    for(int idx = 0; idx < ranges.length; idx++)
        ranges[idx] = rangeSet(a[idx], b[idx]);
    return unionSet(ranges);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped me out. Sorry I can't upvote it because I don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: @MariaJones although please note that this code is _far_ from optimal. I did it in the very simplest, quick-and-dirty way possible. This code would probably be unacceptably slow for most real-world usage. If better performance is needed, modify `lca` to cache values it has already computed (or make it compute more directly), and use a thinner (sparser) data structure instead of the sets.

Comment: You helped me and that's important! :D

Comment: @MariaJones I'd also guess that your prof probably expects a solution much faster than the O(n^2) found here.